# Как убрать повторные (фантомные) нажатия на клавиатуру в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, клавиатура, keypressevent, keyreleaseevent

Мне требуется чтобы программа могла отслеживать **`долгие нажатия`** на клавиши клавиатуры и выполнять одну функцию при нажатии, а другую при отпускании клавиши, причём само нажатие может быть сколь угодно долгим.

Проблема в том, что спустя какое-то время после нажатия клавиша начинает то нажиматься, то отпускаться и это выглядит также как при длительном нажатии в текстовом редакторе: *`жжжж...жжжжж`*).

При этом поочерёдно вызывает методы `keyPressEvent()` и `keyReleaseEvent()` и отследить момент отпуска клавиши становится невозможно.

Вот пример кода, который я использовал (очень сжатый):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('прога')

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print('нажато', chr(event.key()))

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print('отжато', chr(event.key()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

И вывод при зажатии **`ОДНОЙ`** клавиши (примерно за секунду):

```
нажато A
отжато A
нажато A
отжато A
нажато A
...
нажато A
отжато A
```

Очень желательно обойтись без существенных изменений кода и посредством *PyQt5*. Также буду рад любому решению или предположению!

Вероятнее всего проблема возникает от самой клавиатуры, а не от кода. Возможно есть какие-либо способы убрать этот режим из самой клавы (в настройках винды такого нет, я смотрел). Например подключить какую-нибудь библиотеку, позволяющую напрямую влиять на клаву и там уже прописать этот режим. Возможно так будет лучше всего.

Comment: какую функцию вы собираетесь вызывать при отпускании клавиши?, т.е. что должно произойти когда клавиша отпущена после длительного нажатия?

Comment: Программа должна посылать на ардуино сигнал при нажатии(один сигнал) и при отпускании(другой сигнал), и именно так. например для реализации движения робота на стрелочки или wasd

Comment: Попробуйте в ваших методах обработки нажатия вызвать базовые реализации из родительского класса QWidget.keyPressEvent и релиз, соответственно

Comment: хорошо, но, как я понял, проблема возникает из самой клавы, а не из класса, как мне её перенастроить так, чтобы повторные нажатия исчезли?(в настройках винды такого нет, я проверял)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> bool QKeyEvent::**isAutoRepeat()** const
>
> Возвращает `True`, если это событие происходит от автоматически повторяющегося ключа;
> возвращает `False`, если это происходит при первом нажатии клавиши.
>
> Обратите внимание, что если событие представляет собой сжатое событие с `несколькими` клавишами,
> которое частично связано с автоповтором, эта функция может возвращать либо `True`,
> либо `False` неопределенно.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('прога')

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print('>>> нажато', chr(event.key()))
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        
    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if not event.isAutoRepeat():
            print('    отжато <<<<<<', chr(event.key()))
        super().keyReleaseEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хороший ответ :)

Comment: @gil9red спасибо

Comment: Спасибо тебе огроменное, это спасло мой прод.

Comment: @НетёминЕвгений пожалуйста